# How create list with generic argument in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a interface:

```
interface SomeInterface<T>{

}
```

In java i can declare list as follows:

`List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();`

How to write the same in Kotlin? If i try this:

```
var list = ArrayList<PreferenceSerializer>()
```

I get an error
[image: an error]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321). Since `SomeInterface` is generic, you would need to parametrize it. For instance with a wildcard:

```
var list = ArrayList<SomeInterface<*>>()
```